# Grails 2.0.0 mock service always returns true?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have a service in my controller I'm trying to mock but it always returns true. The service looks like this:

`def someService (x, y){...}`

Then I mocked it in my controller test:
`mockservice.demand.someService () {-> return false }`

It keeps returning true. I don't know what's wrong. I tried including the parameters but its still not returning false. How to do this?

PS: Forgive the typos, I am on my phone right now. Thanks

Comment: Parameters has to match while mocking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using this service in an controller, and the unit test is from the controller. I'm assuming also that you read [mocking collaborators](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/testing.html#mockingCollaborators) in the docs.

```
@TestFor(MyController)
class MyControllerSpec {
  def setup() {
    def mockServiceControl = mockFor(SomeService)
    //here you limit the amount of times that the method should be called.
    mockServiceControl.demand.someService(0..1) { x, y ->
      return false
    }
    //probably you're missing to assign the attribute in the controller
    controller.someService = mockServiceControl.createMock()
  }

  void testSomething() {
    controller.action()

    //assert response

    //Then verify that the demand mocking is correct
    mockServiceControl.verify()
  }
}
```

Comment: mockFor() gives a mockControl. you have to call `createMock()` to get the mocked object.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the missing parts. I'm feeling lazy :-)